# What Am I? Alive Without Breath

Tags: riddle, rhyme

The Lord Of The Rings: The Two Towers by J.R.R. Tolkien

> Alive without breath
> As cold as death
> Never thirsting, ever drinking
> Clad in mail, ever clinking
> Drowns on dry land
> Thinks an island
> Is a mountain
> Thinks a fountain
> Is a puff of air
> So sleek, so fair!

What are we?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn’t the answer from the book just

> Fish?

This is more like trivia than a riddle though, given your source?

Comment: Yeah, it is. First post, but I think I got the hang of it now.