# A Strangely Warped Riddle

Tags: riddle

Alive without death

As cold as breath

Clad in mail, never drinking

Never thirsty, always clinking

Hint:

> It's not possible to touch it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Am I? Alive Without Breath](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109766/what-am-i-alive-without-breath) Or is it supposed to be that but with the words moved around?

Comment: @bobble I changed the words to make a new riddle

Comment: Is the answer different?

Comment: @bobble Yes it is

Comment: I'll retract my duplicate vote but leave the comment with a link up

Comment: Clearly the answer is going to be "a shif".

Comment: sounds like a white walker to me

Answer (score -1):

Here is a partial answer:

> Hydrozoan Turritopsis Dohrnii, a jellyfish

Alive without death

> HTD lives forever, and they can repeat their life cycle.

As cold as breath

> I'm not sure about this one, but maybe jellyfishes are **cold**-blooded or the jellyfishes can breathe and the ocean is cold

Clad in mail, never drinking

> A mail-clad is something with armor. Jellyfishes can sting. Jellyfish can also never drink the way that we do. (not sure about the last sentence)

Never thirsty, always clinking

> Working on it

As the title:

> Yes, warped jellyfishes are real!

Comment: That isn't correct